# In a directed acyclic graph, what do you call the nodes with in-degree zero?

Tags: graphs

The question is in the title. What do you call "root nodes" in directed graphs. Is there a commonly accepted term? "Root" implies there's only one, which is not the case. I've scanned half a dozen glossaries before asking. I'm starting to suspect that no, there's no agreed moniker.

Comment: A [forest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forest_(graph_theory)) can have multiple roots, admittedly each tree has only one and in a forest every node belongs only to a single tree.

Comment: @Bergi not all graphs are trees. Directed graphs can have multiple sources, multiple "roots", and still be connected. Trees are a subset of directed acyclic graphs (only one root, and only one path to each node.)

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to add that in forests (a special case of DAGs) there is not only a single root, while "root" is still the commonly accepted term for them. Otherwise see Russel's answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe the common term for that is [**source**](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Source.html). While a node with 0 out-degree is called a [**sink**](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigraphSink.html).

Comment: Also note this applies to all directed graphs, not just directed acyclic graphs.

Comment: There may also be a more specific term that reflects the semantics of the graph in question. For example if the graph represents a finite state machine, the nodes might be referred to as "initial states" and "final states".

Comment: @MichaelKay isn't it possible for an initial state to have in coming edges and final states have outgoing edges?

Comment: Not under the usual definitions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine

Comment: @MichaelKay Actually it depends. [From wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine#Mathematical_model) I don't see any mention that the set $F$ of final states must be such that $\delta(s,x) = s$ or undefined for any $s \in F$ or that the initial state doesn't have incoming edges. In fact with Buchi automata and finite states commonly have outgoing edges since the definition for acceptance in that case involves states that are visited an infinite number of times while recognizing an $\omega$-word.

Comment: @MichaelKay Your link does not appear to support your assertion. The mentions of "initial" and "final" in that document are not associated with in-degree or out-degree anywhere that I can see.

Comment: Agreed, it doesn't model it that way. Looking at the "turnstile" diagram, it says that there are two states "locked" and "unlocked" and that "locked" is the initial state, but the graph shows a little unnamed black dot, which is the node that I think of as the initial state but which isn't mentioned in this formalisation.